# Checking Symbolic Equation Equality in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equality, symbolic-math

How can one check if symbolic eq1 is equal to symbolic eq2 in Matlab:

```
syms a x y
eq1 = a*(x+y)
eq2 = a*x + a*y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`simplify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) on the difference, then [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/logical.html) to test if it is equal to 0:

```
eqAreEqual = logical(simplify(eq1-eq2) == 0);
```

You could also use [`simplify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) on each and [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequal.html) for comparison:

```
eqAreEqual = isequal(simplify(eq1), simplify(eq2));
```

For example:

```
>> syms a x y
>> eq1 = a*(x+y);
>> eq2 = a*x + a*y;
>> eqAreEqual = logical(simplify(eq1-eq2) == 0)

eqAreEqual =

  logical

   1  % True!

>> eqAreEqual = isequal(simplify(eq1), simplify(eq2))

eqAreEqual =

  logical

   1  % Also true!
```

Answer (score 2):

For symbolic math and Matlab R2012a+, in general it's best to use [`isAlways`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) to check if an equality or inequality holds. For your example,

```
isAlways(eq1==eq2)
```

returns logical `true` (`1`). The `isAlways` function considers assumptions and can gracefully handle undecidable conditions. The solution from @gnovice can be used in older versions of Matlab, but will fail by throwing an error when an expression can't be proved, e.g., `logical(simplify(2*x >= x))`.